# Google +1 Button integration in Android

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I am integrating Google +1 Button in Android, every thing works fine but after completing Sharing  +1 button start working and never comes back. A waiting sign is seen on button.

Please help me

mPlusClient is connected

```
mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
String URL="https://developers.google.com/+";
mPlusOneButton.initialize(Navigator.mPlusClient, URL, 0);
```

Comment: have you initialized the PlusClient object in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

mplusbutton needed to be initialized in onResume.